# Raspberry Pi 2 and Qt 5.7 - make stuck at `../qtbase/bin/qmake -conf ../qtbase/qt.conf -o Makefile qt.pro`

Tags: qt, build, native, raspberry-pi2

I trying to compile a native build of **Qt 5.7** (I've yet to do a cross-compilation of that thing...) on the **Raspberry Pi 2**. I have followed the [tutorial on the official Qt wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi). The `configure` step I have is:

```
./configure -v -opengl es2 -tslib -force-pkg-config -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/ \
 -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -qt-pcre -make libs \
 -prefix /usr/local/qt5 2>&1 | tee config.out
```

And my setup is similar to the one in the tutorial - I'm using an external USB stick with `ext4` file system mounted at `/media/USB` and that a `mount --bind` from `/media/USB/build/QT_SRC` to `/opt/QT_SRC`. Prerequirements have been installed (including the `libxcb-xinerama0` and `libxcb-xinerama0-dev` which the article points out as necessary for Qt5.6 and later). A !1GB `swapfile` was added to USB drive too.

After I executed `./configure` I did

```
time make -j3 2>&1 | tee make.out
```

I've also tried plain `make` (without support of parallel compilation and linking). The result is the same:

```
/opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qmake -qtconf /opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile qt.pro
/opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qmake -qtconf /opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile qt.pro
/opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qmake -qtconf /opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile qt.pro
/opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qmake -qtconf /opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile qt.pro
/opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qmake -qtconf /opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile qt.pro
/opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qmake -qtconf /opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile qt.pro
...
...
...
/opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qmake -qtconf /opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile qt.pro
```

This is all that I'm getting. It repeats and repeats itself A LOT OF TIMES and for a LONG PERIOD OF TIME. I wanted to do part of the build while I was sleeping so I just ran `make` before I went to bed...6.5 hours ago. Now that I'm awake I found this...result. I obviously have the `qmake` in there otherwise an error would have been triggered but I have no idea what is happening here.

Has anyone tried to build **Qt 5.7 on Raspberry Pi 2** and encountered this weird issue?

Comment: There are debian packages for Qt 5.7 in debian/experimental. I'll try to rebuild it for jessie, first for amd64 architecture and then for armhf on raspberry pi or qemu user emulator environment.

Comment: I've given up on the QEMU for now. I tried to make it work a couple of times but every time I was getting different errors no matter which kernel I took. As for the Jessie build - I have a Debian Jessie (64bit) on my notebook AND a Qt 5.6 build from source on it so if the reason for doing that is to check if it builds without any problems, then yes, it builds properly. If you can point me to a QEMU tutorial fro RPi2 and Debian Jessie that actually works, I would love to use it. Still the issue I've described is really weird and even if I do it differently I'd still like to know why it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the top level `configure` is not working properly (at least in my case...). I had to go inside `qtbase` and run it from there. You can follow most of the instructions from the [official guide on building Qt 5 natively](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt5_on_a_Raspberry_Pi) on the Pi but it appears that not everything will be compiled and installed. The solution of this problem came from [this post](http://www.ics.com/blog/building-qt-5-raspberry-pi) where it says:

1. `cd` to the top level directory of the Qt 5's sources

   ```
   $ cd QT_SRC_ROOT_DIRECTORY
   ```
2. Choose which modules you would like to build and install and do

   ```
   $ for module in qtcharts qtdatavis3d qtimageformats qtsvg ...;
   > do
   > cd QT_SRC_ROOT_DIRECTORY/$module
   > QT_SRC_ROOT_DIRECTORY/qtbase/bin/qmake
   > make
   > sudo make install
   > done
   ```

This basically loops through each module by going inside, running `qmake` (that is why you first have to compile what's inside `qtbase` so that you can have the `qmake` binary - except for the `qtbase` all other modules are based on `pro` files that is Qt project files which can be used only with a `qmake` tool), then `make` and finally `sudo make install`.

I used absolute paths (unlike in the mentioned blog post) since the `../$module` inside the `for` loop didn't actually work but using absolute paths worked like a charm. So in my case I had /opt/QT_SRC as my `QT_SRC_ROOT_DIRECTORY` so I added it in that loop for accessing each `$module`. The `qmake` in my case was at `/opt/QT_SRC/qtbase/bin/qmake`.

Hope this helps someone else. I now have fully functional `Qt 5.7` on my `Raspberry Pi 2` including the **GPL** modules `QtCharts` and `QtDataVisualization`. Just tested the touch examples as well as the OpenGL Qt cube example - wonderful!

**PS:** The documenation on both native and cross-compile builds for the Pi needs serious updates and fixing...And research how to do things properly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem building Qt 5.7 on Raspberry Pi 3. I solved it by building and installing all modules individually, starting with qtbase like this:

```
$ .../qtbase/bin/qmake
$ make
$ make install
```

The order of building is important. I can't remember the order I followed but, some of the Qt modules yield an error if they need another module built first. Error messages are like this:

> Some of the required modules (qtHaveModule(???)) are not available

I didn't build a few modules like qtwayland, qtwebview or qtwebengine because they need some other stuff installed and I don't need them.
After building Qt 5.7 and configuring my Raspberry Pi, I can run all my Qt applications successfully.